# Move wp-content to shared location - aws

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

I'm creating new Wordpress project and I want to make it easily scalable. It will be hosted on AWS (`EC2` + `RDS`). I set up `autoscaling group` + `code deploy` and `Jenkins` builds and deploy the project after pushing into `master` branch. Now I have following question:

Shall I move whole `wp-content` out of the server and put it in some place available from other machines in the network? It would allow to keep content separately from the core project code and have it in one location.  I cannot just move it to another server, because WP requires it to be available from filesystem. I was thinking about moving it to `S3`, but it does not seem to be good idea.

Can someone more experienced with WP advice what is the best option here?

Comment: You could use Amazon EFS (https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) for that.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that. But is it correct approach at all? (I mean to move plugins, themes, uploads etc out of the core project)

Comment: EFS is the recommended approach, you'll find it described in the [reference AWS wordpress archtecture](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-refarch-wordpress).